# aplay -l doesn't see my loopback sound card

Tags: alsa

I want the only device on this headless system to be the loopback audio. One application will produce audio that will serve as the input to a streaming server.

But `aplay -l` (and other programs that enumerate audio devices) don't see it

```
$ ls -l /proc/asound/cards
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 18 18:22 /proc/asound/cards

$ cat /proc/asound/cards
0 [Loopback       ]: Loopback - Loopback
                      Loopback 1

$ aplay -l
aplay: device_list:268: no soundcards found...
```

Here's my `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

```
alias snd-card-0 snd-aloop
options snd-aloop index=0 pcm_substreams=2

alias snd-card-1 snd-pcm
options snd-pcm index=1
```

Here's the output of `ls -l /dev/snd`

```
crw-rw---- 1 root audio 116,  6 Mar 18 19:07 controlC0
crw-rw---- 1 root audio 116,  5 Mar 18 19:15 pcmC0D0c
crw-rw---- 1 root audio 116,  4 Mar 18 19:15 pcmC0D0p
crw-rw---- 1 root audio 116,  3 Mar 18 19:15 pcmC0D1c
crw-rw---- 1 root audio 116,  2 Mar 18 19:07 pcmC0D1p
crw-rw---- 1 root audio 116,  1 Mar 18 18:49 seq
crw-rw---- 1 root audio 116, 33 Mar 18 19:07 timer
```

Any thoughts? I'm on 14.04.

Comment: Show the output of `ls -l /dev/snd/`.

Comment: Added above. See below for solution.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it! I needed to be in the group "audio" to make it all work.

Fixed with

```
usermod -a -G audio [username]
```

It makes sense from seeing the ownership of the devices in `/dev/snd`, I guess, but I didn't figure this out until I saw an unrelated tutorial on how to get sound to work on rasberian

Comment: +1 but I think this way is now preferable: `sudo adduser $USER audio` :)